# std. residuals in binomial regression

Tags: multiple-regression

A student ran a binomial regression (in SPSS) on an experiment to determine if dusting rodents with Delta Dust reduced flea load on the animals. There are data from two years. The model analyzed by treatment, age, sex, treatment by year, and area. She would like to make a graph for presence of fleas in treated and control for each of the two years. The model for the first year tells us that 37.4% of the rodents in the control had fleas with a 3.1 std. residual, whereas in the dusted group 12.6% had fleas with a -4.4 std. residual. This came in an SPSS summary titled "Treatment by fleas absence presence crosstabulation." A pearson chi-square in the model shows very high significance. The model summary gives an r-squared of .201, but that is the summary and not just the individual comparison of treated and untreated crosstabulation. She would like to draw a figure for the difference between treated and untreated in each of the two years (results were similar for the second year, so I'll just supply information for the first year). The model does not give confidence intervals for the data on treated and control data. Are the std residuals close enough to std error so that the std. residuals could be used to place error bars on the 37.4% and the 12.6% (control and dusted)? The model did create a box above the fleas present/absence crosstabulation. It is in the general summary part and is titled "Variables in the Equation." For each group of treatment, sex, age, area, session, it gives columns titles B, S.E. Wald, df, Sig. Exp(B) and upper / lower 95% confidence interval for Exp(B). For treatment, B is 1.231, S.E. is .243, Wald is 25.736, df is 1, Sig is 0.000, Exp(B) is 3.424. while lower 95% C.I. is 2,126 while upper is 5.5. I am not familiar with SPSS. Are these treatment C.I. levels applicable to her data on presence absence crosstabulation? My email is brimillg@gmail.com. Any help is greatly appreciated. brian

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Please upload screenshots of the output, as the unformatted text you provided of the output above is difficult to read and interpret.  Alternatively, you can format the text into a table to show the columns and the values of those columns

Comment: I tried to edit the message with Word.  I hope that is better.  Sorry, I don't know what screenshots are.  I'm old.  The main question is whether she can use std residuals from a binomial regression as error bars when presenting her data graphically.